# Combining two tables using MERGE

Tags: oracle, join, merge

I am trying to combine two tables vertically

table A

```
ID   Salary                        
A        50                              
B       100
```

table B

```
ID   Salary
C        50
D       200
```

I am trying get a table that looks like

```
ID   Salary
A        50                     
B       100
C        50
D       200
```

I am using this:

```
merge into table_a a using (
  select id, salary from table B
) b
on (a.id = b.id);
```

This is not working.

Comment: First thing: that's not pl/sql. Second thing: that merge statement is missing more options, as XING pointed out. Third thing: you just want to query that, or indeed merge the data? If you want to query, use the union operator, as SMA wrote.

Comment: `from table B` looks wrong. Should that be `from table_b`? (Plus the missing `insert`/`update` sections as mentioned by others.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Merge` syntax is not correct. See below. Read more about Merge [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)

```
MERGE INTO Table_a a
     USING (SELECT Id, Salary FROM TABLE B) b
ON a.id = b.id
when not matched then
insert 
(id,salary) 
values
(b.id,b.salary);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Union or union all

SELECT Id, Salary FROM TableA

UNION

SELECT Id, Salary FROM TableB

Answer (score 0):

I implement some steps here, you can follow each of them

Step 1 : I create 2 tables “table_a” and “table_b”

```
create table table_a(ID varchar2(10),salary number(10));

create table table_b(ID varchar2(10),salary number(10));
```

Step 2: fill them with data:

```
insert into table_a(id,salary) values ('A',50);
insert into table_a(id,salary) values ('B',100);

insert into table_b(id,salary) values ('C',50);
insert into table_b(id,salary) values ('D',200);
```

Step 3: the merge statement here, Be careful you have to use statement “when matched then“

```
merge into table_a a
using table_b b
on (a.id = b.id)
when matched then
  update set a.salary = b.salary
when not matched then
  insert (id, salary) values (b.id, b.salary);
```